# How configure jbossfuse 7.0 in cluster on standalone mode

Tags: configuration, jbossfuse

I want to install Fuse 7.0 on the servers of my company. Before with Fuse 6.3 to install a cluster I used Fabric ... What is the best way to do it with Fuse 7? Is it possible with the Fuse Standalone version?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Fuse 7 has built in cluster management when you use Fuse on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) deployments.  If you don't want to use OpenShift, then you will need to manage/automate the cluster of standalone Fuse JVMs yourself. [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) is a great tool for this kind of thing, but definitely different from how Fabric used to work in Fuse 6.3.